# AngularJs not showing image from list items

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a simple list defined in angular:

```
defaultPointer.list=[
            {name:'Scott',age:29,img:'http://localhost/learn/angular/img/1.jpg'},
            {name:'Steve',age:19,img:'http://localhost/learn/angular/img/2.jpg'},
            {name:'Ben',age:39,img:'http://localhost/learn/angular/img/3.jpg'},
            {name:'Penny',age:12,img:'http://localhost/learn/angular/img/4.jpg'}
            ];
```

Following is the HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in defaultPointer.list | filter:defaultPointer.search">
                <img ng-src="{{ x.img }}"/> <span>{{x.name | uppercase}} is {{ x.age }}</span>
            </li>
```

For some reason, it's showing empty space and no errors in console. What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: is the url of the image correct? and is it "img/1.jpg" or "img1.jpg"?

Comment: A couple of questions that might help: 1.  Is a server running at localhost that has the images?  2.  What is the port?

Comment: incase you are running you application on the same server as your images are on, then no need to use absolute url, try using relative url for the images like `/learn/angular/img/1.jpg`

Comment: I'm using the xampp server, port 80, and yes the url is correct, also I've tried both paths

Comment: Have you checked the CSS attributes in the element inspector? The images may be loaded but either invisible or not have a width value

Comment: inspect and see if there is actual path in `src`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use my code and check it:

```
defaultPointer.list=[
            {name:'Scott',age:29,img:'img/1.jpg'},
            {name:'Steve',age:19,img:'img/2.jpg'},
            {name:'Ben',age:39,img:'img/3.jpg'},
            {name:'Penny',age:12,img:'img/4.jpg'}
            ];
```

Following is the HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in defaultPointer.list | filter:defaultPointer.search">
                <img ng-src="{{ x.img }}"/> <span>{{x.name | uppercase}} is {{ x.age }}</span>
            </li>
```

You have to place this html file in angular folder.